# Can the iOS keyboard be programmed not to automatically insert a period for two spaces?

Tags: ios, keyboard, uitextfield, keyboard-shortcuts, shortcut

On the iOS platform, I have a `UITextField` where I am using the ASCII keyboard layout. I notice (like the keyboard works in other apps) that when I type <kbd>space</kbd> + <kbd>space</kbd>, a period '.' is inserted into the text field. This is all normal iOS stuff...

But can I configure the text field or the keyboard somehow so that this "two spaces == period" behavior is turned off?

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution (albeit not a perfect one) has been posted here ... http://www.mailinglistarchive.com/phoenix-iphone-developer-group@googlegroups.com/msg00037.html